# convert the php array object string to php object variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have an api call which returns data

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TransactionId] => 10254
            [RequestId] => 1548
            [ResponseTime] => 0.161
            [SSP] => test1542
            [ErrorCode] => 0
            [NREC] => 1
            [BILREC] => 1
            [TC] => 0
            [USID] => BQ10
            [ASInput] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [User] => test1254
                    [HostIP] => 124.1.1.1
                    [CS] => test
                    [RId] => 16546asdfs
                    [DPPAPurpose] => 2
                    [GLBPurpose] => 3
                    [PermissibleUseCode] => 3
                    [NumberOfRecords] => 100
                    [StartingRecord] => 1
                    [Version] => 32
                    [Address] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Line1] => 125 main st
                            [City] => BROOKLYN
                            [State] => NY
                            [Zip] => 11237
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

To prevent the multiple call to api for testing how can I convert this to regular php array object so that i can use this output coming in this format to a variable.

```
    $string = "stdClass Object
    (
        [data] => stdClass Object
            (
                [TransactionId] => 10254
                [RequestId] => 1548
                [ResponseTime] => 0.161
                [SSP] => test1542
                [ErrorCode] => 0
                [NREC] => 1
                [BILREC] => 1
                [TC] => 0
                [USID] => BQ10
                [ASInput] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [User] => test1254
                        [HostIP] => 124.1.1.1
                        [CS] => test
                        [RId] => 16546asdfs
                        [DPPAPurpose] => 2
                        [GLBPurpose] => 3
                        [PermissibleUseCode] => 3
                        [NumberOfRecords] => 100
                        [StartingRecord] => 1
                        [Version] => 32
                        [Address] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [Line1] => 125 main st
                                [City] => BROOKLYN
                                [State] => NY
                                [Zip] => 11237
                            )

                    )
            )
    )";
    $array_obj = somefunction($string);
```

Something like that.

Comment: Leave it as an object, why convert it, its perfectly usable like this

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do?

Comment: Do you mean you want to serialize it and save it to a local file so you can re-hydrate it without calling the api again?

Comment: You could iterate it, passing each value to an array and force (string) casting, but I don't see the point in doing that. Can you provide the code that generates this output?

Comment: when i run the print_r($api_return) that the output i get. Now i am trying to create the proper format for html. But while testing i have to call the api over and over for the output. so if i can convert above data to php array that will save my api credits

Comment: @user2986104 I think everyone (including me) is confused by why you would not be able to use it while it's an object. You can output the object properties into HTML just as easily as you could array indices.

Comment: i have edited the question if it will be helpful.

Comment: I'm still confused. Once $api_return receives the result of your api request, you can manipulate it as long as the runtime allows you to, right? There is still no clear need of new callings to the api.

Comment: yes, u are right. but i am trying to convert the api output to nice html design format. but when u run the code it may not display as u want and once you make the design changes u have to again rerun the code which is recalling the api.

Comment: I don't get the point. So you don't want the object array? You want is a pure array?

Comment: I think I understand your issue, but please notice that your question isn't saying that. It seems you can't manipulate objects but can do so with arrays, for whatever reason that is not clear yet, since obj and arrays share mostly the same data structure and can be accessed one as easily as the other.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to simulate your object data to understand your issue.

```
Class ApiObj {

    public $data;

}

Class ApiObjData {

    public $TransactionId = 10254;
    public $RequestId = 1548;
    public $ResponseTime = 0.161;
    public $SSP = 'test1542';
    public $ErrorCode = 0;
    public $NREC = 1;
    public $BILREC = 1;
    public $TC = 0;
    public $USID = 'BQ10';
    public $ASInput;

}

Class ApiObjDataASInput {

    public $User = 'test1254';
    public $HostIP = '124.1.1.1';
    public $CS = 'test';
    public $RId = '16546asdfs';
    public $DPPAPurpose = 2;
    public $GLBPurpose = 3;
    public $PermissibleUseCode = 3;
    public $NumberOfRecords = 100;
    public $StartingRecord = 1;
    public $Version = 32;
    public $Address;
}

Class ApiObjDataASInputAddress {

    public $Line1 = '125 main st';
    public $City = 'BROOKLYN';
    public $State = 'NY';
    public $Zip = 11237;
}

$api_response = new ApiObj;
$api_response->data = new ApiObjData;
$api_response->data->ASInput = new ApiObjDataASInput;
$api_response->data->ASInput->Address = new ApiObjDataASInputAddress;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($api_response);
```

And I've got similiar output:

```
ApiObj Object
(
    [data] => ApiObjData Object
        (
            [TransactionId] => 10254
            [RequestId] => 1548
            [ResponseTime] => 0.161
            [SSP] => test1542
            [ErrorCode] => 0
            [NREC] => 1
            [BILREC] => 1
            [TC] => 0
            [USID] => BQ10
            [ASInput] => ApiObjDataASInput Object
                (
                    [User] => test1254
                    [HostIP] => 124.1.1.1
                    [CS] => test
                    [RId] => 16546asdfs
                    [DPPAPurpose] => 2
                    [GLBPurpose] => 3
                    [PermissibleUseCode] => 3
                    [NumberOfRecords] => 100
                    [StartingRecord] => 1
                    [Version] => 32
                    [Address] => ApiObjDataASInputAddress Object
                        (
                            [Line1] => 125 main st
                            [City] => BROOKLYN
                            [State] => NY
                            [Zip] => 11237
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

As you can see, the data inside the objects can be accessed **just as they would be inside an array**, because object structure **matches** the one of an array. They have similar behavior.

You can parse it, iterate it, echo it, do whatever you want with it, regardless if it is an object or array.

That said, **there is no reason for you to do that**. Whatever is the problem you're facing, any answers to your question as it is presented **won't solve it**.

I suggest you analyze your issue better and ask again, or try to approach it in another context.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a stdobj to an array in PHP:

```
<?php
$data_array = (array) $obj->data;
```

Comment: The way I interpreted the question, the asker wanted the object in array format.

Comment: That's what it sounded like to me too, however, this will only convert the outer part. all of the sub-objects will still be objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but I think you may be wanting to construct an object yourself like the one the API outputs, so that you can experiment on it instead of making repeated API calls. If that is the case, there are a couple of ways to do that. Here is one:

```
$object = new stdClass;
$object->data = new stdClass;
$object->data->TransactionId = 10254;
$object->data->RequestId = 1548;
$object->data->ResponseTime = 0.161;
$object->data->SSP = 'test1542';
$object->data->ErrorCode = 0;
$object->data->NREC = 1;
$object->data->BILREC = 1;
$object->data->TC = 0;
$object->data->USID = 'BQ10';
$object->data->ASInput = new stdClass;
$object->data->ASInput->User = 'test1254';
$object->data->ASInput->HostIP = '124.1.1.1';
$object->data->ASInput->CS = 'test';
$object->data->ASInput->RId = '16546asdfs';
$object->data->ASInput->DPPAPurpose = 2;
$object->data->ASInput->GLBPurpose = 3;
$object->data->ASInput->PermissibleUseCode = 3;
$object->data->ASInput->NumberOfRecords = 100;
$object->data->ASInput->StartingRecord = 1;
$object->data->ASInput->Version = 32;
$object->data->ASInput->Address = new stdClass;
$object->data->ASInput->Address->Line1 = '125 main st';
$object->data->ASInput->Address->City = 'BROOKLYN';
$object->data->ASInput->Address->State = 'NY';
$object->data->ASInput->Address->Zip = '11237';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the class you showed us is the result of an API call that returns a JSON String which you run through a `json_decode();`something like this.

```
$json_string = $api_get(....);
$obj = json_decode($json_string);
```

This creates the json string into an equivalent PHP data type, an Object in this case.

Now if you just change the `json_decode();` and add the second param as `true` it will do the conversion of the json string to a PHP array regardless of the original data type of the json string.

So instead do

```
$json_string = $api_get(....);
$array = json_decode($json_string,true);
```

And you will get an array as a result.